# How to display table with row detailed in MVC

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, datatables

I'm trying to view data on a table from sql data base in MVC view.
the table should contain rows for (Items) and child rows for (sub items)
First of all i read the table records as json from controller and send the result to data table in view.
The Items had appear in table but sub items not.
can Any one help me!

My controller code :

```
    using Budget_system.Models;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Data;
using Sitecore.FakeDb;
using System.IO;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System.Web.Helpers;

namespace Budget_system.Controllers
{
    public class BudgetSystemController : Controller
    {
        private List<ItemsData> Data = new List<ItemsData>();
        private List<ItemsData> Data1 = new List<ItemsData>();

        public object SubItems { get; private set; }

        public ActionResult Items()
        {
             SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection();
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
            cn.ConnectionString = "Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=Budget System;Integrated Security=SSPI";
            cmd.Connection = cn;
            cmd.Connection.Open();
            cmd.CommandText = "select ID,_Name,_Department,_Type,_OpenAmmount  from Items where _year='" + 2019 + "'";
            SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

            while (dr.Read())
            {

                Data.Add(new ItemsData() { ID = int.Parse(dr[0].ToString()), Name = dr[1].ToString(), Department = dr[2].ToString(), Type = (dr[3].ToString()), ItemOpenAmmount = float.Parse((dr[4].ToString())) });
            }
            return View("Items",Data);
        }
        public ActionResult Create(ItemsData itemsData)
        {


            using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection("data source =.; database = Budget System; integrated security = SSPI; "))
            {
                try
                {
                    connection.Open();
                    SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("select ID,_Name,_Department,_Type,_OpenAmmount  from Items where YEAR='" + DateTime.Now.Year.ToString() + "' ", connection);
                    int numOfRows = command.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    command = new SqlCommand("SELECT TOP 1 * FROM Items   ORDER BY ID DESC", connection);
                     int ID = (int)command.ExecuteScalar();

                    if (itemsData.SubItems != null)
                    {
                        for (int i = 0; i < itemsData.OpenAmmount.Count; i++)
                        {
                            if (itemsData.OpenAmmount[i].ToString() != "" && itemsData.SubItems[i] != "")
                            {
                                command = new SqlCommand("insert into SubItems values('" + ID + "','" + itemsData.SubItems[i] + "','" + itemsData.OpenAmmount[i].ToString() + "');", connection);
                                command.ExecuteNonQuery();

                            }
                        }

                    }
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    ViewData["Error"] = ex.Message;
                }
                finally
                {
                    connection.Close();

                }
            }
            return View("Create");
        }
        public ActionResult collectData(ItemsData itemsData)
        {
            using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection("data source =.; database = Budget System; integrated security = SSPI; ")) 
            {
                try
                {
                    connection.Open();
                    SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("insert into Items values('" + itemsData.Name + "','" + itemsData.Year + "','" + itemsData.Department + "','" + itemsData.Divistions + "','" + itemsData.Type + "','" + itemsData.ItemOpenAmmount + "') ", connection);
                    command.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    command = new SqlCommand("SELECT TOP 1 * FROM Items   ORDER BY ID DESC", connection);
                    int ID = (int)command.ExecuteScalar();
                    if (itemsData.SubItems!= null)
                    {
                        for (int i=0;i<itemsData.OpenAmmount.Count;i++)
                        {
                            if (itemsData.OpenAmmount[i].ToString() != ""&&itemsData.SubItems[i]!="")
                            {
                                command = new SqlCommand("insert into SubItems values('" + ID + "','"+itemsData.SubItems[i]+"','" + itemsData.OpenAmmount[i].ToString() + "');", connection);
                                command.ExecuteNonQuery();

                            }
                        }

                    }
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    ViewData["Error"] = ex.Message;
                }
                finally
                {
                    connection.Close();

                }
            }
            return View("Create");
        }


        public JsonResult GetDetail(int id)
        {
            SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection();
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
            cn.ConnectionString = "Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=Budget System;Integrated Security=SSPI";
            cmd.Connection = cn;
            cmd.Connection.Open();
            cmd.CommandText = "select _subID,_Name,_OpenAmmount   from SubItems where _subID='" + id + "'";
            SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            while (dr.Read())
            {

                Data1.Add(new ItemsData() { subItemID = int.Parse(dr[0].ToString()), SubItems = ((List<string>)dr[1]), OpenAmmount = (List<float>)dr[2] });
            }
            return Json((from c in Data1
                         where c.ID == id
                     select c.Name).First(), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);

        }


    }
}
```

My model class:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace Budget_system.Models
{
    public class ItemsData
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }

        public List<string> SubItems { get; set; } 


    public int subItemID { get; set; }
        public string Year { get; set; }
        public string Department { get; set; }
        public string Divistions { get; set; }
        public string Type { get; set; }
        public List<float> OpenAmmount { get; set; }
        public float ItemOpenAmmount { get; set; }

    }
}
```

My view:

```
@model IEnumerable<Budget_system.Models.ItemsData>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-3.4.1.js"></script>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Items";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_LayoutPage1.cshtml";
}
<script>

    var colCount;
    $(document).ready(function () {
        colCount = $(".tbl tr:first").children().length;
        $("tr:odd").css("background-color", "#f0f3f4");
        $(".pm").click(function () {
            if ($(this).hasClass("plus")) {
                $(this).removeClass("plus").addClass("minus");
                if (!$(this).closest("tr").next().hasClass("detail")) {
getDetail($(this).closest("tr"));
                }
                else
                    $(this).closest("tr").next().show();
            }
            else {
                if ($(this).closest("tr").next().hasClass("detail"))
                    $(this).closest("tr").next().hide();
                $(this).removeClass("minus").addClass("plus");
            }
        });
    });
    function getDetail(row) {
        var rowNew = $("<tr class='detail'><td colspan=" + colCount + "></td></tr>");
        $.ajax({
            timeout: 30000,
            data: "id=" + row.find("td:eq(1)").html(),
            url: '@Url.Action("GetDetail")',
            dataType: "json",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            success: function (result) {
                rowNew.find("td").append("<b>Address </b>: " + result.ID);
                rowNew.find("td").append("<b>Sex </b>: " + result.ID);
                rowNew.find("td").append("<b>Nationality </b>: " + result.ID);
                row.after(rowNew);
            },
            error: function (a, b, c) {
                debugger;
            }
        });
    }
    </script>


    <h2>Index</h2>
    <style>
        .tbl {
            border: 1px solid gray;
        }

            .tbl td {
                padding: 5px 10px 5px 10px;
            }

            .tbl th {
                padding: 5px 10px 5px 10px;
                background-color: Gray;
                color: White
            }

        .pm {
            cursor: pointer;
        }

        .plus {
            background: url('http://www.quimicasuiza.com/images/extras/plus-minus.gif') 0 -16px;
            display: block;
            width: 16px;
            height: 16px;
        }

        .minus {
            background: url('http://www.quimicasuiza.com/images/extras/plus-minus.gif') 0 0;
            display: block;
            width: 16px;
            height: 16px;
        }

        .detail {
            background-color: #d4d0d8;
            padding: 7px;
        }
    </style>
    <table class="tbl" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
        <tr><th>&nbsp;</th><th>Id</th><th>Name</th><th>Department</th></tr>
        @foreach (var row in Model)
        {
            <tr><td><span class="pm plus"></span></td><td>@row.ID</td><td>@row.Name</td><td>@row.Department</td></tr>
        }
    </table>
```

Comment: You are missing a starting `<script>` tag for your javascript. Is this just a typo in the code sample?

Comment: @zgood I forget copy it from visual studio to here. but it placed in my origin code!

Comment: Are you getting any console errors when you click `.pm`? Can you set a breakpoint on `GetDetail` to see if it is getting hit? Or is just nothing happening at all?

Comment: No thing happening, No errors in console , and the `GetDetail` method read the data correctly.

Comment: Maybe structure your tables so that your SubItems is a separate table with a foreign key to your ItemsData?  This will give you a 1 to many relationship and you may be able to create the table that way.